# How to use OrderByDescending on Properties using IListFileItem?

Tags: c#, azure, azure-storage, azure-storage-files

I have following code which will return all list items (files and folders) of specific given azure storage path.

I want to filter it using `OrderByDescending` based on Property `LastModified`

How to achieve this ?

```
 // Get list of all files/directories on the file share 
CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageConnectionString"]);
CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
CloudFileShare fileShare = fileClient.GetShareReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["shareName"]);

var sourceName = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetDirectoryReference((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourceName"]));
IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = sourceName.ListFilesAndDirectories();
var test = (fileList.OrderByDescending(t => t.Uri.AbsolutePath).FirstOrDefault());
```

I tried with casting but `LastModified` is null

```
            fileList.ToList().ForEach(x => ((CloudFileDirectory)x).FetchAttributes());
GetAllSubDir(fileList.OrderByDescending(t => ((CloudFileDirectory)t).Properties.LastModified.Value).FirstOrDefault());
```

instead of `Uri.AbsolutePath` I want to use `LastModified`.

Comment: But `IListFileItem` doesn't *have* a `LastModified` property as far as I can see...

Comment: Yes, it looks like you are trying to treat [`IListFileItem`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.windowsazure.storage.file.ilistfileitem?view=azure-dotnet) like something from the local file system.

Comment: try casting it to "CloudFile" this contains the properties you are looking for :)

Comment: @VisualBean So... there's an answer...

Comment: I tried with cast   still its null updated question pls check

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Have a try at following code. You need to get all files first because ListFilesAndDirectories only returns files and directory in a single level.

```
    List<CloudFile> list = new List<CloudFile>();

    public void Test()
    {
        CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageConnectionString"]);
        CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
        CloudFileShare fileShare = 
        fileClient.GetShareReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["shareName"]);

        var sourceName = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetDirectoryReference((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourceName"]));
        IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = sourceName.ListFilesAndDirectories();
        listFile(fileList);

        var test = (from file in list
                      orderby file.Properties.LastModified descending
                      select file).FirstOrDefault();

    }

    // detect all files in the directory
    public void listFile(IEnumerable<IListFileItem> results)
    {
        foreach (IListFileItem fileItem in results)
        {
            if (fileItem.GetType() == typeof(CloudFileDirectory))
            {
                CloudFileDirectory directory = (CloudFileDirectory)fileItem;
                var res = directory.ListFilesAndDirectories();
                listFile(res);
            }
            else
            {
                CloudFile file = (CloudFile)fileItem;
                file.FetchAttributes();
                list.Add(file);
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: but i dont want to add all files from all folder.
I want to add only those files which are from latest folder.
for example - folders are 
`Main/12
Main/13
Main/14`

than I want only files from Main/14 and will check latest file from this folder.

because all files from all folders will take more time as i have thousands of files.

Comment: i think we can use `OrderByDescending(t => t.Uri.AbsolutePath` to go till `Main/14` folder and then add all files from `Main/14` and desc it using LastModified property ? how to use it in your ans code  can you help ?

Comment: @Neo Of course, but I have few questions. How do you tell which folder is the latest, just folder name(like AbsolutePath) or modified time? If it's modified time, where does the latest folder locate, just under the root of share or in a subfolder?

Comment: we can check same like we did for files. but instead of traverse through all sub-folders we can have list for root folders (not files) and do FetchAttributes and check its LastModified .
For example - 
`Main\Folder1
Main\Folder2`
now we will only traverse through `Folder1 and Folder2 not inside it` and add it into list and check its LastModified property and again go inside that lastets folder and do the same till end

Comment: i did like this added ans pls check

Comment: @Neo Thanks for accepting my answer, I have some suggestions. Your answer code is to detect all files in 1.root aka `sourcename` dir 2. latest subdir of each single level. So you planned to only check files in the latest dirs to find the last modified file, right? But there's a problem, when we update/modify/delete a file to/in one dir, dir's last modified time is not changed as file is. If the file is uploaded to a new dir( created with the file), your code should work, or you may miss the real latest file, in this case I think we need to get all files in the directory.

Comment: yea thanks for pointing this. currently i have folder structure like -
super child folder is only having files , do not have files into middle or root level.

Comment: by the way i wonder why the folder modified date is not changed ? 
it should have to change i observed it does not change why so ?

Comment: @Neo Probably by design, looks like only operations on folder itself update the modified time. Someone has asked [similar question](https://github.com/Azure/azure-storage-net/issues/757).

Answer (score 0):

```
 public static void CheckDate()
        {
            CloudStorageAccount cloudStorageAccount = CloudStorageAccount.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["storageConnectionString"]);
            CloudFileClient fileClient = cloudStorageAccount.CreateCloudFileClient();
            CloudFileShare fileShare =
            fileClient.GetShareReference(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["shareName"]);

            var sourceName = fileShare.GetRootDirectoryReference().GetDirectoryReference((ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["sourceName"]));
            IEnumerable<IListFileItem> fileList = sourceName.ListFilesAndDirectories();

            listFile(fileList);

            var latestFile = (from file in filedataList
                              orderby file.Properties.LastModified descending
                              select file).FirstOrDefault();

            Console.WriteLine(" LastModified Datetime - " + latestFile.Properties.LastModified.Value.DateTime);

        }

        public static void listFile(IEnumerable<IListFileItem> results)
        {
            foreach (var item in results)
            {
                if (item.GetType() == typeof(CloudFileDirectory))
                {
                    CloudFileDirectory dir = (CloudFileDirectory)item;
                    dir.FetchAttributes();
                    dirList.Add(dir);
                }
                else
                {
                    CloudFile file = (CloudFile)item;
                    file.FetchAttributes();
                    filedataList.Add(file);
                }
            }
            if (dirList.Count > 0)
            {
                var latestDir = (from dir in dirList
                                 orderby dir.Properties.LastModified descending
                                 select dir).FirstOrDefault();
                dirList.Clear();
                var result = latestDir.ListFilesAndDirectories();
                listFile(result);
            }
        }
```

Comment: Hi Neo. Could you edit this answer to explain how it answers the question? Presently I am not sure future readers can make much use of it, since it is not clear which bit needed fixing.